# ¿Cómo puedo inyectar lineas de sass dentro de un archivo .scss con Gulp.js?

Tags: sass, gulp

Buen día. Quisiera poder inyectar líneas de código Sass dentro de un archivo `archivo.scss`. Las líneas de código a ser inyectadas se encuentran en el archivo `gulpfile.js` almacenadas en variables. Así:

```
// - gulpfile.js

const gulp = require('gulp')

const linea1 = '@import "carpeta/archivo1"',
      linea2 = '@import "carpeta/archivo2"'
```

```
// - archivo.scss

$alguna-variable: '¡Hola mundo!';

@import "variables"
```

¿cómo puedo usar **Gulp.js** para que modifique el archivo `archivo.scss` y lo deje de la siguiente manera?

```
// - archivo.scss

$alguna-variable: '¡Hola mundo!';

@import "variables"
@import "carpeta/archivo1"
@import "carpeta/archivo2"

// Así debería quedar.
```

Comment: aun sigues teniendo problema?

Comment: Logré resolver agregando los archivos a un archivo que almacenará esos archivos. Luego importo ese archivo almacenador al archivo principal, que es el que se compilará.